# ios::seek_dir и стандарт С++2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день.

Транслятор VS 2017.

Пишу простой код:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void setposition(ifstream* ifsptr, streampos pos, ios::seek_dir d = ios::beg) {
    ifsptr->clear();
    ifsptr->seekg(pos, d);
}

int main() {

    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("a.txt");

    setposition(&ifs, 0, ios::beg);

    return 0;
}
```

Если выставить опцию С++14, то все транслируется.

Если выставить опцию С++17, то возникает ошибка:

> error C2039: seek_dir: не является членом
>   "std::basic_ios>"

Вопрос:

1. Как теперь обратиться к этому перечислению?

Спасибо.

UPD1:

А что делать, если требуется, чтобы код транслировался и на более старых версиях, например на VS 2010? Опять дефайнами исправлять косяки?

UPD2:

Господа/товарищи/братья/сестры не надо стирать слова "Добрый день" и "Спасибо" в моих или чьих-либо других постах. Никакой стаковерфлоу не отменяет правил эпистолярной вежливости в русском языке. Так же как не отменяет он правил грамматики, пунктуации, стилистики и личной гигиены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void setposition(ifstream* ifsptr, streampos pos, ios::seekdir d = ios::beg) 
{
```

Годится и для `/std:c++14`.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало. Кроссафчеги ......, чем им подчеркивание-то мешало?

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Оно им не "мешало". Его там просто и не было с самого начала.

Answer (score 2):

C самого начала стандартизованных времен (С++98) в стандартной библиотеке С++ типом для задания направления всегда был именно `std::ios_base::seekdir`. Никаких проблем с использованием `std::ios_base::seekdir` в более ранних реализациях у вас не будет. Вы должны были использовать именно этот тип с самого начала.

А тип `std::ios_base::seek_dir` всегда являлся deprecated. Этот тип существовал в `std::ios_base` на "птичьих" правах только для обратной совместимости с достандартными реализациями.